Is it possible for tomcat 10 to use for the SessionId a UUID-Format instead of the 32-Char String?
We are using tomcat 10 and wanting to have the JSessionId in a UUID-Format
Example:

Currently: JSESSIONID is something like F3C96ED225C9FC87C7C87BBE670FBEEB
Prefered State: f3c96ed2-25c9-fc87-c7c8-7bbe670fbeeb

